# C++ multi thread application hangs forever

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

Consider the next C++ code fragment which represnets (pseudo) multi thread 
application which has two threads, the main thread responsible for getting new 
data (e.g., new frame from video stream) and the secondary thread which needs to 
process the data (e.g., filter the frame), this should happen in parallel so, for example, when the main thread acquires the first frame the second thread does not do anything, when the main thread acquires the second frame the second thread process the first frame and so on.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
using namespace std;
bool StartProcessFromMain = false;
bool FinishedProcess = false;
mutex Main2Process;
mutex Process2Main;
condition_variable CVMain2Process;
condition_variable CVProcess2Main;
void Process();
int main()
{
    long long int Iter = 0;
    // start data process thread
    thread ProcessThread(Process);
    StartProcessFromMain = true;
    CVMain2Process.notify_one();


    // this is the main data acquiring thread
    unique_lock<mutex> lk2(Process2Main);
    lk2.unlock();

    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Iteration: " << ++Iter << endl;
        cout << "Waiting for data processing to finish" << endl;
        lk2.lock();
        CVProcess2Main.wait(lk2, [&] {return FinishedProcess; });
        FinishedProcess = false;
        lk2.unlock();
        cout << "Data processing ended..... getting new data" << endl;
        // getting new data

        cout << "Got new data, calling process thread" << endl;
        StartProcessFromMain = true;
        CVMain2Process.notify_one();

    }
    return 0;
}

void Process()
{
    //data processing thread

    unique_lock<mutex> lk(Main2Process);
    lk.unlock();

    while (true)
    {
        cout << "waiting for new data" << endl;
        lk.lock();
        CVMain2Process.wait(lk, [&] {return StartProcessFromMain; });
        StartProcessFromMain = false;
        lk.unlock();
        // Processing new data here

        // Finished processing new data - notify data acquiring thread
        cout << "Finished processing new data" << endl;
        FinishedProcess = true;
        CVProcess2Main.notify_one();

    }
}
```

In practice, compiled both with MSVC 2015 (x64) on Windows 10  and with gcc on Ubuntu 16.04, this code **always hangs forever**  (usually after thousands or tens of thousands iterations) when both threads wait one for the other :-(

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @freakish - is there a simple way  to prevent that?

Comment: @freakish - do you mean that I need to lock before the line `FinishedProcess = true;` ? what about `StartProcessFromMain = true;`?

Comment: @freakish - the way I see it, nothing prevents the two threads to work in parallel, instead of the `while(true)` in the main thread I could write `while(readFrame(FrameObj)` for example, so when this thread reads the frame the second thread process the *previous* thread

Comment: @freakish -Appreciate that, downvoting good questions became some kind of sport here, don't understand why.

Comment: @freakish - Now I understand that modifying the bools should be made under the same mutex. what about `CVMain2Process.notify_one();` and `CVProcess2Main.notify_one();`? are they also should be under that lock?

Comment: @freakish - In the main thread I  added `unique_lock<mutex> lk(Main2Process);` before `StartProcessFromMain = true;` and `lk.unlock()` right after,  (unlocking before  `CVMain2Process.notify_one();`) and in the second thread I added `unique_lock<mutex> lk2(Process2Main);` before `FinishedProcess = true;`  and `lk2.unlock()` right after. I am running it to see if it solved the problem.  Why do the `.wait()`  calls need to share the same mutex? every thread have its own wainting mutex. I didn't change that.

Comment: @freakish - OK!, I changed that also so now I have only `unique_lock<mutex> lk(Main2Process);` as input to both `wait()` , `unique_lock<mutex> lk2(Process2Main);` no longer exist

Comment: Uh, this is still wrong. I'll be honest: this is unncessarily complicated. I advice switching to queues. Your main thread reads a frame in a loop and each time it does it just enqueues the frame. The other thread simply dequeues next frame and processes it. Something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/3dDPum

Comment: @freakish - But would it happen in parallel? my intention is that the second thread process the current frame while the main thread gets the next frame... Is it Complicated? Wow, and I thought it's the simplest way....

Comment: @BennyK  In the 4th line of main, you signal a cond var.   Why?   Did it immediately hang if you didn't do that?   Condvars do not have memory; semaphores have memory.  If you signal a cond var that nobody is waiting upon, then you have done nothing and the wait will block forever.   Your program happens to work because the threads are operating in near lockstep.  When one falls out of lockstep (maybe a cron job) it hangs on you.

Comment: @BennyK Well, the last code I've shown you will happen in parallel. I've written an alternative version with "switches" instead of queues: https://godbolt.org/z/5WO8JV which is more similar to your original code. The point is that you actually need two mutexes, but both threads have to have access to both of them. So yeah, this is quite complicated, multithreaded programming is not easy at all. That's why I've wraped it into a class. You can even mix queues with switches. Anyway I'm going to bad now, I'm too tired, sorry. Hope it is ok now.

Comment: @mevets because If I won't do that and the second thread will get to `wait` before the bool is true than it will hang there forever, Am I wrong here?  The code usually hangs after more than 10000 iterations so I dont think that is the problem

Comment: @freakish so eventually I do need two different mutexes?

Comment: @BennyK yes, I think so. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to compile your program with any of the c++ versions I could find, so I translated (upgraded?) it to C, then made it work with pthreads.   It is at the bottom.

The most important bit; it uses one mutex and one condvar to protects two flags - ProcessingData, DataAvailable.   These are the fundamental communication between the threads.
The first thread, main, first waits until ProcessingData is false.   This keeps it from interfering with the Process() thread while it is working on the shared data.   Once ProcessingData is false, main is free to go and get fresh data.  It then reacquires the single mutex (MainLock), sets DataAvailable to true, and signals the condvar MainCV.

The second thread, Process, first waits until DataAvailable is true.  This keeps it from interfering with the main() thread while it is off getting new data.  Once DataAvailable is true, it sets ProcessingData to true, goes and processes the data, and once it is done, reacquires the single mutex MainLock, clears ProcessingData and signals the condvar MainCV.

This is free of races; and the threads can continue independently after handshaking the data exchange.   This can be done with two condvars and one mutex, but there isn't really any advantage to it.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
bool        ProcessingData = false;
bool        DataAvailable = false;
pthread_mutex_t MainLock;
pthread_cond_t  MainCV;
pthread_cond_t  MainCV;

void           *Process(void *);
#define X(y)   do { if (y == -1) abort(); } while (0)
int 
main()
{
    X(pthread_mutex_init(&MainLock, NULL));
    X(pthread_cond_init(&MainCV, NULL));
    long        Iter = 0;
    //start data process thread
    pthread_t id;
    X(pthread_create(&id, NULL, Process, NULL));
    X(pthread_cond_signal(&MainCV));

    while (true) {
        printf("Iteration: %ld waiting for processing to finish\n", ++Iter);
        X(pthread_mutex_lock(&MainLock));
        while (ProcessingData) {
            X(pthread_cond_wait(&MainCV, &MainLock));
        }
        X(pthread_mutex_unlock(&MainLock));
        printf("Data processing ended, getting new data\n");
        //getting new data

        printf("Got new data, calling process thread\n");
        X(pthread_mutex_lock(&MainLock));
        DataAvailable = true;
        X(pthread_mutex_unlock(&MainLock));
        X(pthread_cond_signal(&MainCV));

    }
    return 0;
}

void *Process(void *notused)
{
    //data processing thread

    while (true) {
        printf("waiting for new data\n");
        X(pthread_mutex_lock(&MainLock));
        while (!DataAvailable) {
            X(pthread_cond_wait(&MainCV, &MainLock));
        }
        ProcessingData = true;
        X(pthread_mutex_unlock(&MainLock));
        //Processing new data here

            // Finished processing new data - notify data acquiring thread
            printf("Finished processing new data\n");
        X(pthread_mutex_lock(&MainLock));
        ProcessingData = false;
        X(pthread_mutex_unlock(&MainLock));
        X(pthread_cond_signal(&MainCV));

    }
}
```